# How to apply a function to text inside all <td> tags, if text a number?

Tags: javascript

I have an html page that is basically some headers and a series of tables.  Tables are populated both with numbers and strings.  The number of tables and the contents of a table will vary.

I would like to add a thousands place comma separator for numbers >1000 and have found the following function to do this:

```
function numberWithCommas(number) {
   var parts = number.toString().split(".");
   parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
   return parts.join(".");
}
```

Using javascript, how can I apply this function to all of the numbers on my page?

Comment: So loop over the table cells, read the text, and apply it? Or even better, do it to what is generating the table in the first place?

Comment: _“all of the numbers on my page”_ might require quite a complex solution; it would be way easier if you could specify upfront which table cells contain those numbers - selection via a class, position inside the rows, etc.. And whether those cells contain _only_ those numbers, or if those numbers need to be parsed out of longer texts in the first place, would also be quite important. Please show a proper example of what your tables look like.

Comment: The reason I say "all of the numbers" is because I would like to apply this method to different pages.  I'm looking for a one size fits all solutions..  perhaps that's a stretch.

Could I grab all the text from a page, check if the text could be parsed to a number, and then apply my function to those texts?

Comment: As epascarello said, it would be better and easier to do it, when generating the table.
For formating the numbers you could use `number.toLocaleString('de')`, to generate a string with commas as decimal-separator

Comment: Why is it better to do when generating the table?  Seems like adding commas should be done as a very last step because it makes numbers incrementally harder to work with.  To me, Javascript in the html layer seemed the most natural place to do this

Comment: Otherwise you have to write all numbers to the table and then read and write them again when altering. That's not good for the performance. How do you generate the table? Usually writing those is the very last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is just a bunch of table details with data in them, you could just map over all of them like so:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td')).forEach(detail => {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(detail.innerText)) && detail.innerText.length > 3) {
    detail.innerText = numberWithCommas(detail.innerText);
  }
})
```

Comment: map() is the wrong thing to use. Yes it works, but you should be using something like forEach

Comment: this works well for my purposes.  I used `parseFloat()` instead

Comment: Note that NaN is never equal to NaN.  I used `!isNaN(parseInt(detail.innerText))` instead to get desired result